# NodeJS CoffeeScript variable scope and callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I currently developping a Coffeescript with nodejs that would allows me to dump all images on a Tumblr.

In a first loop it execute a request that will get a list of all the images on each page via the API.

In a second loop, it download all the images.

the problem is that, I don't know why, the first callback is never executed, the "start" counter is never incremented.

Here is the code :

```
xml2json = require "xml2json"
fs = require "fs"
util = require "util"
request = require "request"

tumblr_name = process.argv[2]
api_endpoint = util.format "http://%s.tumblr.com/api/read", tumblr_name
start = 0
num = 50
post_count = 50

download = (uri, filename) ->
  request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename))

while post_count > 0
  console.log util.format "post_count: %s - num: %s", post_count, num
  page_uri = util.format "%s?type=photo&start=%s&num=%s", api_endpoint, start, num
  do (page_uri) ->
    request page_uri, (error, response, body) ->
      console.log util.format "Downloading %s", page_uri
      data_xml = body
      data_json = JSON.parse xml2json.toJson data_xml
      post_count = data_json["tumblr"]["posts"]["post"].length
      for post in data_json["tumblr"]["posts"]["post"]
        post_id = post["id"]
        post_date = post["date-gmt"].split(" ")[0]
        for photo in post["photo-url"]
          if photo["max-width"] == 1280
            outname = util.format "%s-%s-%s.%s", tumblr_name, post_date, post_id, photo["$t"].split(".").slice(-1)[0]
            download photo["$t"], outname
  start = start + num
```

Comment: Have you checked if `post_count` is greater than `0` and if the loop even runs?

Comment: Yes it does run, I did some check with console.log

Comment: And you don't get the `Downloading %s` `console.log`, right? Also, try to use some parens in function calls, some lines are really hard to read (fe. `data_json = JSON.parse xml2json.toJson data_xml` would be easier to read like that: `data_json = JSON.parse(xml2json.toJson(data_xml))`)

Comment: Yep, I don't get the Downloading %s, I confirm